# Override users `remember_me` token in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I want same `remember_token` to be generated when we use generator ==> `php artisan make:auth`.
Here is what I'm creating new `user`.

```
 $user = User::create(['name' => $request->name,'email' => $request->email,'password' => bcrypt($request->password),'phone' => $request->phone,'address' => $request->address]);
```

but I don't know how to generate `remember_token`.

```
 $user = User::create(['...'=>'...','remember_token' => what()]);
```

> I already have created remember_token in my database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using the default `User.php` model that ships with Laravel, then you can override the method `setRememberToken($token)`:

```
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    public function setRememberToken($token)
    {
        // Set the remember token your own way...

        $this->remember_token = 'my random token';
    }
}
```

This is called in the `EloquentUserProvider` here:

https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.4/src/Illuminate/Auth/EloquentUserProvider.php#L71-L89

```
/**
 * Update the "remember me" token for the given user in storage.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable  $user
 * @param  string  $token
 * @return void
 */
public function updateRememberToken(UserContract $user, $token)
{
    $user->setRememberToken($token);

    $timestamps = $user->timestamps;

    $user->timestamps = false;

    $user->save();

    $user->timestamps = $timestamps;
}
```

Comment: it seems to me very complicated as i'm new to laravel, please help me furthur i would provide you my controller code.. please!!!

Comment: my main goal is to implement `forgot password` feature

Comment: Laravel already has a forgot password feature, it's built in?

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/passwords